# Spring Security SAML: 403 Forbidden when attempting single sign-on

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I'm developing a Spring application that uses single sign-on, using the [Spring Security SAML Extension sample application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html) as a starting point. I went through the steps in the Quick Start Guide to generate SP metadata and upload it to SSOCircle. When I try to test SSO with SSOCircle, I get a 403 error.

Here's my securityContext.xml. I'm not sure what's wrong with my configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

    <security:http security="none" pattern="/login.htm"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/index.jsp"/>

    <!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
    <security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
        <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    </security:http>

    <!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/fileupload.htm"/>
    </bean>
    <!--
    Use the following for interpreting RelayState coming from unsolicited response as redirect URL:
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler">
       <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
    </bean>
    -->

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
    <bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.htm?failure=true"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler for successful logout -->
    <bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout.htm"/>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
        <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
    <bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger">
        <!-- Enable these to see the actual SAML Messages in logs -->
        <!-- <property name="logAllMessages" value="true"/>  -->
        <!-- <property name="logErrors" value="true"/>  -->
        <!-- <property name="logMessagesOnException" value="true"/>  -->
    </bean>

    <!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
    <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
    <bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
        <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
                <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
    <bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
<!--         <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp"/> -->
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
    <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
                <property name="entityId" value="com:web:fileupload"/>
                <property name="extendedMetadata">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
                        <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
    <bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

    <!-- Configure HTTP Client to accept certificates from the keystore for HTTPS verification -->
    <!--
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer">
        <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
    </bean>
    -->

    <!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
    <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value type="java.lang.String">http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value type="int">5000</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider" id="samlAuthenticationProvider">
        <property ref="samlUserDetailsService" name="userDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.web.services.AuthSamlUserDetailsService" id="samlUserDetailsService">
        <property name="roles">
            <list>
                <value>ROLE_USER</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
    <bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
    <bean id="logoutHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
        <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
    <!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
    <bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
                <ref bean="postBinding"/>
                <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
                <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
                <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
    <bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
    <bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
    <bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="processor">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                        <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

    <!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

    <!-- 
        XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing

        WARNING: If customizing a ParserPool implementation See https://shibboleth.net/community/advisories/secadv_20131213.txt
                 Specifically the following should be explicitly set to avoid exploits:

                 1) set pool property 'expandEntityReferences' to 'false'
                 2) set feature 'javax.xml.XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING' to true
                 3) set feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl' to true. This is a Xerces-specific feature,
                    including derivatives such as the internal JAXP implementations supplied with the Oracle and OpenJDK JREs. For
                    other JAXP implementations, consult the documentation for the implementation for guidance on how to achieve a
                    similar configuration.
    -->
    <bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize"/>

    <bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>

</beans>
```

EDIT: I've tried to solve this problem with a different IDP and this is the response I'm getting back

```
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                 Destination="https://127.0.0.1:8443/file-upload/saml/SSO"
                 ID="_23129487a2984cda91afabe74baae509"
                 InResponseTo="a2dc03c0b38e0ggi2jhdeij54g2552c"
                 IssueInstant="2019-06-26T21:01:53.052Z"
                 Version="2.0"
                 >
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://samltest.id/saml/idp</saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#_23129487a2984cda91afabe74baae509">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <ds:DigestValue>neGOpeSJcjawIJEgUUqr5SU1Z9qp2ZrpELu5EpT5xBA=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>...</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml2p:Status xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                            Id="_6a138db978470e7c919472ccc7d3ba74"
                            Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
                            >
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                                   Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"
                                   />
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                                   Id="_2a5fc19f2af47e0adf67bbf54198602f"
                                   Recipient="com:web:fileupload"
                                   >
                    <xenc:EncryptionMethod xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                                           Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"
                                           >
                        <ds:DigestMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                                         Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"
                                         />
                    </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
                    <ds:KeyInfo>
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                    <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                        <xenc:CipherValue>...</xenc:CipherValue>
                    </xenc:CipherData>
                </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:CipherValue>...</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </saml2:EncryptedAssertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Comment: Where do you get the 403 from and at which part of the SAML SP-initiated SSO flow?

Comment: I get the 403 when I click "Continue SAML Single Sign-On" after logging into my account. I'm using a free SSOCircle account so I can't debug from there, but I used Chrome's developer console to determine that the 403 did return a SAML response. So I suspect that the IDP response was rejected by the SP.